# Brightness stucked on max

Tags: brightness, backlight

My brightness is stuck on max. When I try decrease it by keyboard, the brightness' UI tells me that the brightness is decreasing, but visually it doesnt happens. I tried change directly in the backlights files, but didn't worked.

I'm on a notebook, Ubuntu 15.04. I already tried reinstall Ubuntu, change the OS, but the problem doesnt disappear. Can someone help me?

Comment: It would be helpful to know the brand and model of your notebook computer. It's also possible that upgrading Ubuntu to 16.04, the latest version, will solve the issue. (It is highly recommended to do so anyway, since 15.04 is no longer recieving security updates!!!)